# Selectively clearing a list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow

I have a list in SharePoint which has 26 columns and I have a task to delete the contents of all rows except the first 4 columns. How can I do this automatically?

I created a flow in Power Automate but it turned out only a stream that deletes all lines. Maybe there are another methods? Thank you.

Comment: How many items are there in this SharePoint list?

Comment: From 50 to 400. I have different lists for which this needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a Flow - err, Power Automate. You'll need to fetch all the list items, iterate them, and then edit each one as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quick Edit as a workaround.
You can open an empty Excel workbook, copy the empty cells and then paste them in the SharePoint list using Quick Edit.
This can also quickly clear the values of multiple columns. Hope this can help you.

Comment: This is an interesting way, thanks, but in my list there are select columns and calculated columns with which this method does not work